# css selectors correctly identify items in scrapy shell but not when I run the spider

Tags: python, css, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

The CSV returns all empty links except the 'href' tag. I think it may have something to do with the get request. I read somewhere that you can only perform one then you have to parse, I'm just not sure I'm going about it the right way.

```py
import scrapy

class StylevanaspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stylevanaspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.stylevana.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.stylevana.com/en_US/skincare.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('li.product-item').get()
        for product in products:
            yield{
                'name': product.css('li.product-item > div.product-item-details > h2::text').get(),
                'price': product.css('li.product-item > div.product-item-details > div.price-box').get(),
                #'old_price': product.css('li.product-item > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.price-box > span > span.price::text').get(),
                'url': product.css('li.product-item > div > div > div > a').attrib['href'],
            }
        
        
        next_page_url = f'https://www.stylevana.com/en_US/skincare.html/?p={page_num}'
        for page_num in range(2,875):
            yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self. Parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving empty output because the website is strongly protected by Cloudflare protection even it didn't work with selenium, CloudScraper, I tried but didn't work. Show the proven below:

```
https://www.stylevana.com/en_US/skincare.html

https://www.stylevana.com/en_US/skincare.html is using Cloudflare DNS!

Checked 8 global locations, found DNS entries for Cloudflare in 4

Found in: England, China, Russia, USA

Not found in: Denmark, Germany, Spain, Netherlands

https://www.stylevana.com/en_US/skincare.html is using Cloudflare CDN/Proxy!

https://www.stylevana.com/en_US/skincare.html is NOT using Cloudflare SSL
```